# Read csv files to separate dataframes based on a grouping variable

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

Given 20k csv files, and a tibble defining the groups of data the csv files contain & the file names of the csv files:

```
df <- tibble(
  group = c("group_1", "group_1", "group_2", "group_3"), 
  file_name = c("file_1.csv", "file_2.csv", "file_3.csv", "file_4.csv")
)
```

**I need to import the csv files and rbind to dataframes but a seperate dataframe for each group**

The files might not have the same columns, so if you just import all the files and bind at step 1 there will be columns to remove later. So ideally I need a process that starts with the groups, reads the relevant files, binds rows and then outputs as a dataframe which is named the same as the group.

I can import the csv files with lapply, read.csv & bind_rows, but I can't seem to work out how to generalize that process dependent on how many groups there are.

An lapply or purrr based solution would be preferable.

Cheers

Comment: With purrr, maybe something like `df %>% split(.$group) %>% map(~map_df(.x$file_name, read.csv, .id = 'group'))`

Comment: Maybe neater, nest instead of splitting: `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(file_name = list(file_name)) %>% mutate(data = map(file_name, ~map_df(.x, read_csv, .id = 'file')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
dff <- tibble(
  group = c("group_1", "group_1", "group_2", "group_3"), 
  file_name = c("file_1.csv", "file_2.csv", "file_3.csv", "file_4.csv")
)

lapply(split(dff, dff$group), function(x) {
    do.call(rbind, lapply(x$file_name, read.csv))
})
```

I hope this helps.